# Capture File Properties and Owner Details

Tags: vba, excel

I have two VBA codes. One loops through and prints the file properties, and the other grabs the owner of a file.

How do I merge the File Owner VBA code into File Properties to print the file name, modification date and owner onto a sheet?

**File Properties - VBA**

```vb
Sub MainList()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set Folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If Folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDir = Folder.SelectedItems(1)
    Call ListFilesInFolder(xDir, True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
    
Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    
    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
    
    rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Path
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 2).Formula = xFile.Name
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 3).Formula = xFile.DateLastAccessed
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 4).Formula = xFile.DateLastModified
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 5).Formula = xFile.DateCreated
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 6).Formula = xFile.Type
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 7).Formula = xFile.Size
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 8).Formula = xFile.Owner
      ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(C[-7])"
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next xFile
    If xIsSubfolders Then
      For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.Path, True
      Next xSubFolder
    End If
    Set xFile = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

**File Owner - VBA**

```
Sub test()
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fDir As String
    fName = "FileName.JPG"
    fDir = "C:/FilePath"
    Range("A1").Value = GetFileOwner(fDir, fName)
End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String
    Dim securityUtility As Object
    Dim securityDescriptor As Object
    Set securityUtility = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
    Set securityDescriptor = securityUtility.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
    GetFileOwner = securityDescriptor.Owner
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Without refactoring it, if you change this line of code;

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 8).Formula = xFile.Owner
```

To this;

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 8).Formula = GetFileOwner(xFolderName, xFile.Name)
```

It will call the GetFileOwner function and should do the trick for you.