# Macro to save the owner of a file in a folder to variable 'owner'

Tags: vba

I have written a code that opens a specific folder and what I need it to do is check the owner of each file stored within the folder and check to see if the owner is myself (currentUser) or not. I have written all the logic up until getting the variable 'owner' without automatically declaring the variable myself which I do not want since the owner name will change based on the file within the folder.

```
Private Sub CountPDFFilesOwnedByCurrentUser()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileCount As Long
    Dim file As String
    Dim owner As String
    Dim currentUser As String

    folderPath = "I:\PUBLIC\Presentation Slides\"

    
    currentUser = "COMPANY\" + Environ("USERNAME")

    ' Initialize the file count
    fileCount = 0

    ' Loop through files in the folder
    file = Dir(folderPath & "\*.*")
    Do While file <> ""
        ' Get the owner of the file  (need to implement this logic)
        owner = "John Doe"

        ' Check if the owner matches the current user and the file type is "Microsoft Edge PDF Document"
        If owner = currentUser And Right(file, 4) = ".pdf" Then    
            fileCount = fileCount + 1
        End If

        ' Get the next file
        file = Dir
    Loop

    ' Display the result
    MsgBox "Number of Microsoft Edge PDF Documents owned by " & currentUser & ": " & fileCount
End Sub
```

When I say I want the code to read the owner of the file, this is the header of 'owner' I mean in file explorer. For privacy reasons there are no names shown.

[File Explorer Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBBJ.png)

UPDATED CODE RUNNING

```
Private Sub CountPDFFilesOwnedByCurrentUser()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim fileCount As Long
Dim file As String
Dim owner As String
Dim currentUser As String

folderPath = "I:\PUBLIC\Presentation Slides\"
currentUser = "COMPANY\" + Environ("USERNAME")

' Initialize the file count
fileCount = 0

' Loop through files in the folder
file = Dir(folderPath & "\*.pdf")
Do While file <> ""
  
Range("A5").Value = GetFileOwner(folderPath, file)

    If owner = currentUser Then 
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
    End If

    ' Get the next file
    file = Dir
Loop
End Sub


Function GetFileOwner(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String

  ' On Error Resume Next
 Dim securityUtility As Object
 Dim securityDescriptor As Object
 Set securityUtility = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
 Set securityDescriptor = securityUtility.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
 GetFileOwner = securityDescriptor.owner
 MsgBox (GetFileOwner)
End Function
```

[Message Box with Output for GetFileOwner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPSOZ.png)

Comment: Btw, you can restrict to just PDF files using `Dir(folderPath & "\*.pdf")`, no need for `Right(file, 4) = ".pdf"`.

Comment: How to get the file owner: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41897239/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams I have reviewed the post from the link you provided, but in using that code, the value of GetFileOwner gives me a long number rather than a users name - by chance is that because of the use of `securityDescriptor.owner`?

Comment: In testing, I get (eg) `MYCORP\timwilliams` so I'm not sure what's different between my setup and yours.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added the setup I am running to show you

Comment: Can you show an example of what you get instead of the domain\username ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have added a picture of my output

Comment: That looks like a SID https://kb.iu.edu/d/aotl#:~:text=The%20SID%20(Security%20IDentifier)%20is,as%20Indiana%20University's%20Active%20Directory. You should be able to convert that to the username using something like this:  https://www.devhut.net/vba-retrieve-windows-sid-and-username/#:~:text=Retrieving%20the%20Account%20UserName%20Based%20On%20An%20SID   I sometimes get a SID when the person's account is no longer active.